# What's the name of this pattern (submitting an entry which gets added to a table)?

Tags: forms, design-patterns, terminology

In this example the user would enter an item number and add it to the list:

[image: entered content gets added to a table]

Does this particular pattern has a name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this pattern can be called " List Entry View ". Full description can be found [here](http://www.welie.com/patterns/showPattern.php?patternID=list-entry-view), [All list of patterns](http://www.welie.com/patterns/index.php)

Comment: Actually it's much more close to the list builder pattern, but the question is specific about the "add to list" functionality which is not mentioned in neither patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The list as you have shown is called [List View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or [Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html). The method, which you have shown is inserting a new record to the existing view.